# Coil, Fresco and Glide can't decode jpeg image due to unknown image format

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide, fresco, coil

I tried to use Coil, Glide and Fresco in Jetpack Compose to load and show [image](https://c.dns-shop.ru/thumb/st4/fit/200/200/04d0ba06bcd6368cef034b0ff1f84fea/f7ab30662cb7df554dcd3cf872287b8b4ff3c10cf524175e8f3f1836328eede9.jpg) but got an error due to decoding

Firstly i checked Coil and got next error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BitmapFactory returned a null bitmap. Often this means BitmapFactory could not decode the image data read from the input source (e.g. network, disk, or memory) as it's not encoded as a valid image format.
```

Then Glide:

```
Load failed for [https://c.dns-shop.ru/thumb/st4/fit/200/200/04d0ba06bcd6368cef034b0ff1f84fea/f7ab30662cb7df554dcd3cf872287b8b4ff3c10cf524175e8f3f1836328eede9.jpg] with dimensions [1080x722]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{->Object->Drawable}, REMOTE
        Cause (1 of 4): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{->Drawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 4): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 4): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{->Bitmap->BitmapDrawable}
        Cause (4 of 4): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
```

And Fresco:

```
ProgressiveDecoder: unknown image format, {uri: https://c.dns-shop.ru/thumb/st4/fit/200/200/04d0ba06bcd6368cef034b0ff1f84fea/f7ab30662cb7df554dcd3cf872287b8b4ff3c10cf524175e8f3f1836328eede9.jpg, firstEncodedBytes: 15BE1C006400E7B69FCA, length: 7279}
```

Every library had similar error due to decoding and wrong format.

[Information about image and meta data here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jreh7.png)

My code:

```kotlin
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                        ) {
                            AsyncImage(
                                model = ImageRequest.Builder(this@MainActivity)
                                    .data(link)
                                    .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
                                    .build(),
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .weight(1f)
                                    .fillMaxSize()
                            )
                            FrescoImage(
                                imageUrl = link,
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .weight(1f)
                                    .fillMaxSize()
                            )
                            GlideImage(
                                model = link,
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .weight(1f)
                                    .fillMaxSize()
                            ) {
                                it.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                            }
                        }
```

How can i solve the problem? Is is possible?

Comment: Eight bits per sample. One byte per pixel. Would that be the problem?

Comment: In Coil's BitmapFactoryDecoder there's this code fragment. It shows that bitmap decoding is delegated to android.graphics.BitmapFactory. All these libraries probably use the same function for bitmap decoding and that's why all of them fail:

        val outBitmap: Bitmap? = safeBufferedSource.use {
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it.inputStream(), null, this)
        }
        checkNotNull(outBitmap) {
            "BitmapFactory returned a null bitmap. [...]"
        }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my app and the reason was that there was an OkHttp interceptor modifying the responses. Make sure that your requests aren't meddled with somewhere.